# How do I install ASP.NET on Raspberry Pi 3 (IoT)?

Tags: asp.net, raspberry-pi, windowsiot

(I'm new/noob to Raspberry Pi and IoT, so please bear with me)

I have latest IoT version 10.0.14295 on my Pi 3.

Is it possible to install ASP.NET 5 on this device?

I haven't been able to find a proper solution - maybe it's not possible at this time?

I've looked at this link: https://www.hackster.io/iddi/windows-10-iot-core-publish-asp-net-web-application-d9dcd4 but it seams like DNVM is dead - so maybe there's a new way to do it?

Comment: could you please let me know how can I download the IoT release for Pi 3?

Comment: @Ummar ... https://developer.microsoft.com/da-dk/windows/iot/Downloads.htm ... in the lower right corner, you'll find IoT Windows 10 for Pi 3.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately there is problem with the support of .NET Core on Windows 10 IoT. I hope it is just a temporary situation. **RC2 is not supported at all**: https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/1531